# Not how to use header and pointer together

Tags: c, header

I have a project that Im having a problem with. So the instructions were that we were suppose to only code in the header file instead of the c file. 
This is the part that im confused with:

> void getName(Name *) - Receives a pointer to a Name and performs the
>   actions described below.
>
> • Prompt the user to enter the required member data for the Name type.
>   First, ask for the first name:
>
> > Please enter the contact’s first name: <
> >     - Read and store the C string value the user enters into the appropriate Name member

I know how to do this in the C file, but im not sure how the header file works. What I have currently in my header file

```
    // Structure type Name declaration (Milestone 1)
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

// Structure type Address declaration 
// Place your code here... (from Milestone 1)

struct Address {
    char street[41];
    int streetNumber[1];
    int apartmentNumber[1];
    char postalCode[8];
    char city [41];
};



// Structure type Numbers declaration
// Place your code here... (from Milestone 1)
struct Numbers {
    int cell[21];
    int home[21];
    int business[21];
};




// Structure type Contact declaration
// Place your code here... (from Milestone 3)

struct Contacts{
    char name;
    char address;
    int number;
};
```

What am I suppose to write to get the Name from the user. The C file is empty, cause im only suppose to use the header file. (Only suppose to use the C file for calling the variable, displaying the title,Call the Contact function getName to store the values for the Name member, etc)

Comment: This seems like a very odd requirement. However, `.h` header files by definition support identical language constructs to a source `.c` file, so you can just write all your code as normal in the header instead. However, I would check with your instructor as to whether or not the requirement to put everything in the header is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could write the entire getName() function in the header file since the C pre-processor will copy-paste the entire header into the C file before compilation.